# Button in gridview that redirects user to url

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, .net-4.0

I'm working on a manager of sorts that allows certain employees to view the results of a survey customers take.  I'm tracking the IP address of the customers that take the survey and displaying that ip address to the employees who can view the results.  I'm using a gridview with an sqldatasource to extract the data out of the database and display it. 
What I would like to do is add a button or link that takes the IP address and appends it to a url of web site to track the location of the ip address on a map.  I have already signed up for a serivce to do this but am unsure of how to code it.

Here is my Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVnewsletterManager" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="email_time" ForeColor="Black" 
    GridLines="Horizontal" Width="100%" PageSize="15">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email_time" HeaderText="Length of Email Subscription" 
            SortExpression="email_time" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="reason" HeaderText="Reason for Unsubscribe" 
            SortExpression="reason" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="other" HeaderText="Other Reason" 
            SortExpression="other" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="other_comments" HeaderText="Other Comments" SortExpression="other_comments" 
            ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateTime" HeaderText="Date" 
            SortExpression="DateTime" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IP" HeaderText="Client IP" SortExpression="IP" />
        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" Text="Trace IP to Map" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" 
        HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Check this: http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/09/23/pass-querystring-parameter-with-navigaterurl-in-hyperlink-inside-a-gridview.aspx

Comment: Leave it as an answer and I'll give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a HyperLinkField

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.aspx

```
<asp:HyperLinkField
                 HeaderText="Client IP"
                 DataNavigateUrlFields="IP"
                 DataNavigateUrlFormatString="some-page.aspx?id={0}"
                 DataTextField="IP"
                 DataTextFormatString="{0}"
                 Target="_blank"/>
```

Comment: Ahh, youre right. I meant HyperLinkField. Editing my response.